# maximizing convex quadratic form over the intersection of unit sphere and positive orthant

Tags: quadratic-forms, convex-optimization

For a positive semi-definite matrix $C$, I want to find the solution to the following problem:

$\arg\max_{h\geq 0} h^T C h\quad$ s.t. $\quad h^T h\leq 1$

Any pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

The magic words are [quadratically constrained quadratic programming.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program) And [semidefinite programming.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidefinite_programming)

**EDIT** I misread the question (it is a convex *maximization* problem). This is still somewhat tractable in practice (since the objective still has convex epigraphs), but see the excellent answer by @NoahStein to [this question.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48843/non-negative-quadratic-maximization)

Comment: http://ghostbusters.wikia.com/wiki/The_Magic_Word

Comment: please note this is a maximization problem so cannot be mapped to a QCQP

Comment: @AbhishekKumar oops, misread the question. See the edit.